# Fire vfx (by route of Quick Smoke) won't work: not matter what I do nothing appears

Tags: workflow, smoke-simulation, fire

Following along with BlenderGuru's tutorials. I got smoke to work using QuickSmoke and making sure domain was selected, not flow, and baked it. Works perfectly! Only roadbump was oddly bake material didn't appear as a button entirely until restarting.

But then when I try to make fire and all comments say to just go to flow and switch to fire or fire and smoke and press play, it doesn't work. It doesn't do anything. It also then breaks the smoke fx. If I duplicate the first object and smoke domain to see if I can have the practice on fire object and the finished smoking object, it breaks both quicksmoke binding objects

Also having an issue with solids (just primatives, nothing big, just the starter cube, monkey head, donut to scale) will flash like a strobe light when I try to use hotkeys. They work fine moving, rotating, etc without hotkeys though this is unpractical, but the second I use any hotkey I get such insane flickering it can't be worked with.

So far everything's just on defaults and I'm using the most recent v 2.82a on a pretty high powered gaming pc